# SoundCloud: I need a function to extract a var for artwork_url from any permalink_url to insert in a DB

Tags: api, soundcloud

My permalink_url example is "https://soundcloud.com/rac/sets/rac-chapter-one". I need a function to produce the artwork_url variable from the permalink url. Similar to thiscode lifted from the Soundcloud docs, but expressed as a function:

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});

// permalink to a track
var track_url = 'https://soundcloud.com/rac/sets/rac-chapter-one';

SC.get('/resolve', { url: track_url }, function(track) {
  SC.get('/tracks/' + track.id + '/comments', function(comments) {
    for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
      console.log('Someone said: ' + comments[i].body);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I am a barely capable player with this type of coding, and would appreciate any practical help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have the `artwork_url` property from the sound representation:

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});

// permalink to a track
var track_url = 'https://soundcloud.com/rac/sets/rac-chapter-one';

SC.get('/resolve', { url: track_url }, function(track) {
  console.log(track.artwork_url);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks gryzzly - haven't had any luck yet though, all Im trying to do is grab the artwork url and enter it in a database. I was hoping there was a simple string of variables on the end on the permalink :)